# Python dictionary giving weird results

Tags: python, json, class, dictionary, inverted-index

I was trying to generate an inverted-index like structure from json response result.

> [{"node":[{"node": [{"node": [{"id": "w"}], "id": "q"}], "id":"e"},{"id":"r"},{"id":"t"}],"id":"y"}, {"id": "u"}]

Here is the sample json data, all I'm trying is to keep track of index of each 'id' object.
for example in the given sample, object with 'id' equal to 'u' have index [1] and object with 'id' equal to 'q' have index [0[0[0]]].

Resultant index representation here is in form of array, so it will be [1] and [0,0,0] respectively.

I have written this code for it all.

```html
class Tree:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.indices = {}

        self.create_index(self.data)

    def create_index(self, data):
        for i in range(len(data)):
            self.trace_node(data[i], i, [])

        print self.indices

    def trace_node(self, node, index, index_list):
        _list = index_list
        _list.append(index)

        self.indices[node['id']] = _list
        print node['id'], _list

        try:
            for i in range(len(node['node'])):
                self.trace_node(node['node'][i], i, _list)
        except:
            pass
```

When I run this code, it prints right result for each node while tracing, but at the end of the execution the **indices** class variable (**dict object**) is left with weird values and I'm just unable to figure it out, why?

Here is the result of execution, I used above given json **data** in this.

> tree = Tree(data)

and it prints this :

y [0]

e [0, 0]

q [0, 0, 0]

w [0, 0, 0, 0]

r [0, 1]

t [0, 2]

u [1]

{'e': [0], 'q': [0], 'r': [0], 'u': [1], 't': [0], 'w': [0], 'y': [0]}

So you can see here that it prints right resultant index array for each 'id' but at the end the class variable **indices** is just showing, don't know what.

> **PS**: Actually I don't believe in asking this kind of personal problems but I'm fighting with this since a whole day. I asked same to my friend and after some time's fight, he also said everything seems fine to me.

So I'm waiting for answer and lesson to learn from it :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Assigning a list to another variable and passing a list as a parameter, do not create a copy of the list. The same list will be referenced by the new variables.

Comment: then what I'm supposed to do? should I use **_list = list();_list = index_list**? I suppose **list()** will create a new empty list. Am I right?

Comment: Given a list, `the_list` using `new_list = the_list[:]` will create a copy of the list that can be changed without affecting the original list.

Comment: Holy Crap !! How come I was still missing this. Thanks thefourtheye and @lanAuld. Its working fine now, Should I delete the question or update an answer?

Comment: @pravj once you get to the root of the issue (assignment doesn't cooy) there are many duplicates of this question; I'd suggest deleting it. Otherwise, you should put the answer *in an answer*, not the question.

Answer (score 0):

As were pointed out in the comment section, you need to copy the list.

Just replace

```
self.indices[node['id']] = _list
```

with

```
self.indices[node['id']] = _list[:]
```

The reason you were seeing weird result is that, all the nodes of same master tree branch are getting same `_list` object assigned to them. And since you are doing `_list.pop()`, the final `_list` becomes list of just the top level index.

Also,`node['ch']` should be `node['node']` in you code snippet. I guess its just a typing mistake :-)